# Using spock to test a complicated JSON string condition is never satisified

Tags: groovy, spock

```
org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
Gradle 1.12
Groovy 1.8.6
```

Hello,

I have a function that will return a JSON string. And I want to test that my function correctly creates the JSON format. However, I am having a problem with maybe some escape characters as the test always fails.

This is the correct JSON format I am expecting and testing against:

```
{"function":"verifyEmail","parameters":[{"email_pwd":"password","session_id":"S1234","snapz_id":"T1234","email":"a@hotmail.com","access_token":"abcd"}]}
```

However, setting up the condition is proving difficult because of the `double quotes` and the `[ ]` characters. I have tried to escape them.

This is the function:

```
def 'Parse the string to create JSON object'() {
    setup:
    def requestFactory = new RequestFactory();
    def snapzJSON = requestFactory.createWSRequest(FunctionReq.VERIFY_EMAIL, accessToken, sessionId, snapzId, email, emailPwd)

    expect: 'Correctly formats JSON string'
    System.out.println("SPOCK TEST: " + snapzJSON.createJSONRequest())
    snapzJSON.createJSONRequest()  == '{\"function\":\"verifyEmail\",\"parameters\":\\[{\"email_pwd\":\"password\",\"session_id\":\"S1234\",\"snapz_id\":\"T1234\",\"email\":\"a@hotmail.com\",\"access_token\":\"abcd\"}\\]}'        
}
```

And this is the result:

```
Condition not satisfied:

snapzJSON.createJSONRequest()  == '{\"function\":\"verifyEmail\",\"parameters\":\\[{\"email_pwd\":\"password\",\"session_id\":\"S1234\",\"snapz_id\":\"T1234\",\"email\":\"a@hotmail.com\",\"access_token\":\"abcd\"}\\]}'
|         |                    |
|         |                    false
|         [parameters:[[session_id:S1234, snapz_id:T1234, email:a@hotmail.com, email_pwd:password, access_token:abcd]], function:verifyEmail]
abcd S1234 T1234 a@hotmail.com password
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Some additional output from test results:

```
jsonObject: {"parameters":[{"session_id":"S1234","snapz_id":"T1234","email":"a@hotmail.com","email_pwd":"password","access_token":"abcd"}],"function":"verifyEmail"}
SPOCK TEST: [parameters:[[session_id:S1234, snapz_id:T1234, email:a@hotmail.com, email_pwd:password, access_token:abcd]], function:verifyEmail]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
snapzJSON.createJSONRequest()  == '{\"function\":\"verifyEmail\",\"parameters\":\\[{\"email_pwd\":\"password\",\"session_id\":\"S1234\",\"snapz_id\":\"T1234\",\"email\":\"a@hotmail.com\",\"access_token\":\"abcd\"}\\]}'
```

You're comparing `String` with `Map`. You need to parse the JSON string on the right (using `JsonSlurper`) and the compare the values. There's also no need to esacpe `"` when single quote used `'`.

You can also serialize left side (`snapzJSON.createJSONRequest()` to string using `JsonOutput`) and then compare.

It's much better to compare maps.